# Writing binary type data in cells structure

Tags: python, binaryfiles

I have an `CSV` file looking something like this:

```
[num]_[num] [num] [string]
```

For example:

```
1234_123 987 Hello World
```

I want to save the this data in a binary file, maintaing somehow the according row structure.
Any ideas?

Comment: It's not a CSV. CSV stands for "comma separated values".

Comment: although you can change what  the seperator is... Im not sure i understand the problem? or the question?

Comment: I didn't understand your comment. My file is indeed `CSV` and the structure is as explained...

Comment: @JoranBeasley The current CSV file is `txt` type. I'm asking how can I save the same data, organized in the structure of rows, but as binary type.

Comment: ummm ... im not sure you understand what the words you are using mean ...

Comment: All files are binary at their basic level. What varies is how they encode the data within them. Pickle will make a binary file. JSON will save your data with the structure intact, although its binary format will be in the form of human-readable characters.

Comment: What is your purpose in converting to this binary format? Maybe that will clarify the requirements.

Comment: What would the binary form of the sample data be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ummm

```
import base64
with open("output.bin","w") as f:
      f.write(base64.b64encode(open("input.txt")
```

if you want to save it in a way that humans cant read (if thats what you mean by binary format)

then decode it back

```
import base64
original_txt = base64.b64decode(open("output.bin").read())
```